# code for vb.net mysql connect next record?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

i joined Mysql database to vb.net, but i want to show one by one next records in the database. i create text-boxes and a next button to view the next records. but i don't know the code how to make the button click to next record.

```
        TextBox1.Text = ds.Tables("aaa").Rows(0).Item(0)

        TextBox2.Text = ds.Tables("aaa").Rows(0).Item(1)

        TextBox3.Text = ds.Tables("aaa").Rows(0).Item(2)

        TextBox4.Text = ds.Tables("aaa").Rows(0).Item(3)
```

this only show 1st record. but i want to view all records one by one.
also want to view previous, first and last record..

Comment: There are convenient tools and built-in for Binding and navigation with data.

for WinForms see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973824.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Mean By This ?

Declare Public Integer

```
Public j As Integer = 0
Public count  As Integer
```

Now Assign number of result to count
    'Number oF items

```
count = ds.Tables("aaa").Columns.Count
```

Now Next Button Click Event

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

   If j <= count Then
     TextBox1.Text = ds.Tables("aaa").Rows(0).Item(j).ToString
   j += 1
   End If

End Sub
```